# Form data are submited as ASCII i need UTF8

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, utf-8

Hi i post the serialized data of a form by jquery ajax to a php script and i found that the data are send as ASCII when i checked them with `mb_detect_encoding`. My php page from where the data are come is declared as UTF8 with this tag `<meta charset=UTF-8"/>`, do i have to add something to the page that the form comes or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASCII is a perfect subset of UTF-8. If UTF-8 encoded data contains only characters in the basic ASCII range, it's indistinguishable from ASCII. I.e. it's both valid ASCII and UTF-8 at the same time.

`mb_detect_encoding` simply guesses the first matching encoding.

Comment: Do i have to know that mb_detect_encoding choose the first matching encoding?